# django test cases can't get past the @login_required decorator on a view function

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-testing

I've scoured stackoverflow and tried several different solutions, but my test code always goes to the login redirect.

This is what I have:

```
class LoggedInSetup(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create(username="lolwutboi", password="whatisthepassword")
        self.client.login(username='lolwutboi', password='whatisthepassword')

        number_of_submissions = 13
        for sub in range(number_of_submissions):
            Submission.objects.create(title='Amazing', description='This is the body of the post',
                                      author=str(self.user), pub_date=timezone.now())


class LoggedInTestCases(LoggedInSetup):

    def test_logged_in_post_reachable(self):
        self.client.login(username='lolwutboi', password='whatisthepassword')
        resp = self.client.get(reverse('submission_post'))
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set the password like that - the password stored in the database is a hashed value and you are setting it to the password string itself. This means the validation will fail.

You would need to [set the password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password) like so:

```
self.user = User.objects.create(username="lolwutboi")
self.user.set_password("whatisthepassword")
self.user.save()
```

However, since all you really need is to log in the test user, use [`force_login`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login) in the test:

```
self.client.force_login(self.user)
```

Which will log in the user without you having to worry about passwords.

Comment: @Shiny_and_Chrome If that solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer! Why is this important: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top